# How to word the message before "Undo" button?

Tags: copywriting, delete, undo

In our web-app's ui there's a few actions you can undo.

For example, you can delete messages or comments. To do that you click delete next to it. Then, there's a message that informs that action was completed and undo.

What is the best way to word the message before "Undo"? Is there any reason to word it in a specific way?

**Message deleted. Undo**

**Message was deleted. Undo**

**The message is deleted. Undo**

**Message has been deleted. Undo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing more of the UI would be helpful. But to take an example that seems to work rather well in what I interpret to be a similar context - that the message appears in a different place from where the button was clicked - let's take two examples: Microsoft Mail and Google Inbox.

[image: Microsoft Mail]

[image: Google Inbox]

Neither bother with an elaborate phrasing.

If you wish to reinforce the fact that a *message* has been deleted, as opposed to something else that they might delete in the same UI context, just go with the most concise `Message deleted. Undo`: it's faster for the brain to parse.

N.B., Definitely not "The message is deleted"; while grammatical, it is not idiomatic in this context and looks like a bad translation.